# Tm1 to python to R

Tags: python, r

I would like to create a dashboard using R. However, all the data that I need to connect is from TM1.

The easiest way that I found is using an python library called TM1py to connect to tm1 data.

I would like to know what is the easist to access to access TM1py library from R ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a requirement to go through Python? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYttNT2vRfU and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=428-zDU2-Qw suggest that you can get data from TM1 into R. I'm pretty sure no one has written a library to integrate these two yet... sounds like a great opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you only want to read data from tm1. Therefore a "simple" mdx query should be fine. Have a look at the package "httr" how to send POST-Requests. Then it's pretty staright forward to port the relevant parts from tm1py to R.

Comment: I am using a Python script to create an  mdx query.
https://github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py-samples/blob/master/Query%20Data/cube%20data%20into%20pandas%20dataframe.py

 Then I use PythonInR library to get this file. Is there a simple way to do this process with httr package ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tm1r package that can be used to access TM1 data by writing REST-APIs to TM1

https://github.com/muhammedalionder/tm1r/blob/master/README.md

The CRAN project link below

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm1r/index.html
data can be imported from 'TM1' via MDX view or native view

An example REST-API call on TM1 to get elements in Dimension
http://localhost:14321/api/v1/Dimensions('Version')/Hierarchies('Version')/Members

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could connect was using tm1py script:

[SCRIPT](http://%20github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py-samples/blob/master/Query%20Data/%E2%80%A6)

Then connect to R via PythonInR library using this command:

```
pyConnect("C:/Users/.../python.exe")
pyExecfile("FILE.py")
data <- pyGet("Data")
```

As Fabian Gehring mentioned, using Httr can be a great way to do this directly, but I still didn't find the best way.